# Value only set after double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm serializing an array and console logging all the values of the array. I need to click a value twice in order to get the correct value logged. And I have started programming a few weeks ago so please keep that in mind when rating this question. Thanks!

```
  $(function() {

    var sir = <?php print_r(json_encode($listings));?>;

    $('.btn-group label').click(function() {

      // Get all inputed data
      var data = $('form.purchase-form').serializeArray();

      console.log(data);

      input = [];

      // Make new array of wanted values
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (data[i].name !== "_token" && data[i].name !== 'item_id' && data[i].name !== 'condition' && data[i].name !== 'payment') {
          input.push(data[i].value);
        }
      }
      console.log(input);
    });
  });
```

For example's sake, lets pretend this is a form:

"B selected on first click":

A **B** C

-> logs B

"C still selected on second click":

A B **C**

-> logs B

Example console log:

0: Object
name: "_token",
value: "MDGsfUfgYIMzd8ETvGaA9tbGlsh6hSchPxWjhNiQ"

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement must be incorrect, and it's not evaluating to true when you expect it to. Also it's basically impossible to help with this problem when you don't show the data you're working off of, because the if condition is tied explicitly to that.

I would put something like the following in.

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data[i].name !== "_token" && data[i].name !== 'item_id' && data[i].name !== 'condition' && data[i].name !== 'payment')
```

Which will help you realize what's not correct about your if statement, or your data, or your assumptions!

EDIT

If this is your only output from it running, then your if check is going to fail, and you're not ever going to push anything into your input var.
The comparison `data[i].name !== "_token"` is false

`0: Object name: "_token", value: "MDGsfUfgYIMzd8ETvGaA9tbGlsh6hSchPxWjhNiQ"`

Comment: Thanks. I added example output